# Management Studio Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am debugging some code and part of that code is to update the recieve column when
Here is the error along with the column I am trying to make NULL (Which has about 4million rows and have plenty of NULLS already in there)
Here is an example of the error (Sorry I couldnt just post the image)

[image: http://s10.postimg.org/uq82horix/image.png]

And here is the design of the table showing you that nulls are allowed...

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/zdqe45d87/image.png]

My coworker said he would normally just do a control 0 and it would allow him to change it to NULL...

The only thing is, I used code to update the table.. Here is a snippet of the code used (Hopefully it looks ok, it doesnt look very good on the preview):

```
//Update a row in shp_detail, start by Query the database for the row to be updated.


int tempInt3 = Convert.ToInt32(strSerialNbr);
var timenow = DateTime.Now;
var ICTUpdate =
    from row in db.shp_detail
    where row.serialnbr == tempInt3
    select row;

//Execute the query, and change the column values you want to change. If need to format row.receive then add .ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff")
foreach (var row in ICTUpdate)
{
    row.receive = timenow;
}
// Submit the changes to the database. 
db.SaveChanges();
MessageBox.Show("Hopefully you just updated the shp_detail table where the serialnbr is: " + strSerialNbr + " recieve column should now be: " + timenow);
//End of Update
```

Comment: So you are getting an error in SQL Server Management Studio interface and you want to know how to set `receive` field to `NULL` through code ????

Comment: No just to change it in the management studio, I am sure I could change it back through code... possibly anyway, but it just seems easier to be able to change it in management studio

Comment: The code portion is just to show you how I changed the recieve feild from null to the current time... but changing it back in management studio gives me this error

Comment: Thanks gunr2171 for the correct editing :)

Comment: Your colleague is right, pressing Ctrl + 0 is same as typing `NULL` *in upper case*. If you have opened that Edit window then try closing it and opening it again. Also try inserting null values through SQL Statement.

Comment: Yes, I understand that... Obviously it does not allow the string "NULL" (Hence the error) ... and that does not make sense to me, which is why I posted the question. =)

Comment: my point is it should allow `NULL`, either to be typed in or by pressing `Ctrl + 0`. If it is not doing that then restart management studio and try again. If the column is set to allow null, it should work.

Comment: I have restarted, I have tried Ctrl + 0 and it still does not allow NULL...

Comment: Is this updating an existing record to set the column to NULL? Are you editing any other columns in the process that aren't shown in the screenshot? Last, what happens if you try to set it to NULL using a SQL Update statement instead of the editor?

Comment: Just tried to run a SQL update in Management studio with success: `UPDATE shp_detail SET receive = NULL WHERE serialnbr = '192595';`

Comment: Dont understand how that is different from just typing it in but it works! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else with this issue:

Just tried to run a SQL update in Management studio with success: UPDATE shp_detail SET receive = NULL WHERE serialnbr = '192595';

Just like Tim Copenhaver suggested..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in SSMS.  Maybe try the following SQL to refresh the definitions?

```
declare @placeholderDate datetime = '1753-01-01 00:00'

update shp_detail
set ship = coalesce(ship,@placeholderDate)
, [receive] = coalesce([receive],@placeholderDate)
, remove = coalesce(remove,@placeholderDate)
where ship is null
or [receive] is null
or remove is null
go

alter table shp_detail 
alter column ship datetime not null
alter table shp_detail 
alter column [receive] datetime not null
alter table shp_detail 
alter column remove datetime not null
go

alter table shp_detail 
alter column ship datetime null
alter table shp_detail 
alter column [receive] datetime null
alter table shp_detail 
alter column remove datetime null
go

declare @placeholderDate datetime = '1753-01-01 00:00'

update shp_detail
set ship = nullif(ship,@placeholderDate)
, [receive] = nullif([receive],@placeholderDate)
, remove = nullif(remove,@placeholderDate)
where ship = @placeholderDate
or [receive] = @placeholderDate
or remove  = @placeholderDate
go
```